# Kafka Producer error Expiring 10 record(s) for TOPIC:XXXXXX: 6686 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka Version : 0.10.2.1,

```
Kafka Producer error Expiring 10 record(s) for TOPIC:XXXXXX: 6686 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 10 record(s) for TOPIC:XXXXXX: 6686 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

Comment: You get this error when the producer can't send data to the broker that it thinks is responsible for the messages according to the metadata that it has. Did the kafka broker die or your producer have connection issues at that time?

Comment: I am also getting this error intermittently throughout the day. Searching for an answer

Comment: Its stopped occurring when I change my kafka producer "max.request.size": "4713360",
"acks": "all",
"timeout.ms":"18000",
"batch.size": "100000", -- this is size in bytes .. 
"linger.ms":"100",
"retries": "5",
"min.insync.replicas":"2",
"buffer.memory ":"66554432",
"request.timeout.ms":"90000","block.on.buffer.full","true"   basically linger.ms and batch.size  and block.on.buffer.full plays major role here

Answer (score 45):

This exception is occurring because you are queueing records at a much faster rate than they can be sent.

When you call the send method, the ProducerRecord will be stored in an internal buffer for sending to the broker. The method returns immediately once the ProducerRecord has been buffered, regardless of whether it has been sent.

Records are grouped into batches for sending to the broker, to reduce the transport overhead per message and increase throughput.

Once a record is added into a batch, there is a time limit for sending that batch to ensure that it has been sent within a specified duration. This is controlled by the Producer configuration parameter, request.timeout.ms, which defaults to 30 seconds. [See related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807188)

If the batch has been queued longer than the timeout limit, the exception will be thrown. Records in that batch will be removed from the send queue.

**Producer configs block.on.buffer.full, metadata.fetch.timeout.ms and timeout.ms have been removed. They were initially deprecated in Kafka 0.9.0.0.**

Therefore give a try for increasing **request.timeout.ms**

Still, if you have any problem related to throughput, you can also refer following [blog](http://ingest.tips/2015/07/19/tips-for-improving-performance-of-kafka-producer/)

Comment: Unfortunately this link is dead to me.

Comment: @CristianoFontes yes, unfortunately, it's down. But Pretty much answer has already been covered above.

Comment: One situation where this might occur is when you start up a job(s) and are moving through backlog at a faster rate than you normally would. That spike in traffic can be difficult for Kafka to handle.

Comment: @arglee this "request.timeout.ms" means the network time taken by the "Sender thread" to send the buffered messages ?

Comment: @CristianoFontes  will the kafka producer  do the retry(if retry set in producer config >3) in case of "xxx ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time" ?

Comment: For those looking for the blog post, it can be found on web archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20181027004036/http://ingest.tips/2015/07/19/tips-for-improving-performance-of-kafka-producer/

Answer (score 2):

This issue originates when wither brokers/topics/partitions are not able to contact with producer or producer times out before the queue.

I found that even for a live brokers you can encounter this issue. In my case, the topic partitions leaders were pointing to inactive broker ids. To fix this issue, you have to migrate those leaders to active brokers.

Use topic-reassignment tool for impacted topics. 
Topic Migration: https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation.html#basic_ops_automigrate

Answer (score 1):

I had same message and I fixed it cleaning the kafka data from zookeeper. After that it's working.

Comment: Did you just clear certain things out of ZK or drop all Kafka managed data for ZK?

Comment: In my case, I cleaned all ZK data.

Comment: Can anyone please guide me on how I can do that? I am facing the exact problem and except for cleaning the data, have tried it all! I am willing to clean all zk data but not able to understand how!

Answer (score 1):

i had faced same issue in aks cluster, just restarting of kafka and zookeeper servers resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**FOR KAFKA DOCKER CASE**

For a lot of time find out what happened, including changes `server.properties` , `producer.properties` and my code (Eclipse). That does not work for me (I send message from my laptop to Kafka Docker on a Linux server)

I cleaned Kafka and Zookeeper and reinstall them by docker-compose.yml(I'm newbie). Please look at my `docker-compose.yml` file and follow how I changes these IP to my Linux server's IP

***bitnami/kafka***

[bitnami/kafka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6aFc.png)

to...

[bitnami-changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyMXK.png)

*while 10.5.1.30 is my Linux server's IP address*

***wurstmeister kafka***

[wurstmeister](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTj8x.png)

after that, I ran my code and here's result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC0rn.png)

**full code:**

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata;

public class SimpleProducer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            String topicName = "demo";
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("bootstrap.servers", "10.5.1.30:9092");
            props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
            props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
            Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
            Future<RecordMetadata> f = producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName, "Eclipse3"));
            System.out.println("Message sent successfully, total of message is: " + f.get().toString());
            producer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Successful");

    }
}
```

Hope that helps. Peace !!!

Comment: Changing Kafka containers doesn't fix the error in the title. Only having `f.get()` and `producer.close()` is causing the batch not to expire

Answer (score 0):

Check 2 producer configuration parameters:

- max.block.ms - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#max-block-ms
- buffer.memory - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#buffer-memory

Answer (score -1):

Say a topic has 100 partitions (0-99). Kafka lets you produce records to a topic by specifying a particular partition. Faced the issue where I'm trying to produce to partition > 99, because brokers reject these records.

Answer (score -2):

We tried everything, but no luck.

1. Decreased producer batch size and increased request.timeout.ms.
2. Restarted target kafka cluster, still no luck.
3. Checked replication on target kafka cluster, that as well was working fine.
4. Added retries, retries.backout.ms in prodcuer properties.
5. Added linger.time as well in kafka prodcuer properties.

Finally our case there was issue with kafka cluster itself, from 2 servers we were unable to fetch metadata in between.

When we changed target kafka cluster to our dev box, it worked fine.